# Using geopoint on Elasticsearch from Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, geoip

I want  to use geoip in elk stack from docker.
according to this documentation I added config

https://www.elastic.co/blog/geoip-in-the-elastic-stack

this is my logstash.conf

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}

filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}" }
  }
  geoip {
    source => "clientip"
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "elasticsearch:9200"
    manage_template => false
    index => "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }
}
```

and I know I should add this json in some place . but I don't know where should I do this?

```
"geoip"  : {
  "dynamic": true,
  "properties" : {
    "ip": { "type": "ip" },
    "location" : { "type" : "geo_point" },
    "latitude" : { "type" : "half_float" },
    "longitude" : { "type" : "half_float" }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logstash pipeline is fine. The json you're trying to add is a mapping that is automatically generated by logstash.

Considering you are using a Kibana with your Elasticsearch cluster :

```
go to management -> index patern -> Create Index Pattern -> type "logstash-*" or a name that fits your need with this index -> select 
timestamp and hit "create index pattern".
```

If at this step you can't visualize geoip data, it could be that the IPs that are in your data are not relevant in the public area.
You can try your IPs here : https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip-demo